# Response.redirect throwing "Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent" error in Sitefinity

Tags: c#, content-management-system, sitefinity

Custom widget for back-end administrator login throwing "Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent" error on Response.Redirect of successful login. Anything specifically to be added to avoid error. Need some help to solve this issue.

Comment: The error message indicates you are trying to modify the response after it was sent.  If this is the 2nd response you have to create a new response (not reuse the first response).

Comment: It is a button click for login and if username and password matched it redirects to dashboard using Response.Redirect("/sitefinity/dashboard")l

Comment: You can only send back one response for each request.  The error indicates you are trying to modify the response after the response was sent.

Comment: how about you remove your Response.Redirect and let Sitefinity do it

Comment: I am having this response.redirect in a custom widget in stiefinity. It is a login widget, so on successful login it should redirect to dashboard. Is there a way to make this redirection possible without response.redirect

Comment: Is it possible to do OTP validation in sitefinity without using custom widget and just by using sitefinity default widget